# jQuery, how to load AJAX JSON data into html data elements with less code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a working script loading AJAX file using $.getJSON and loading it into 2 html tags.
I would like to extend the JSON file and feed different data to some 30 tags.
JSON string is defined the same as the tag Id which I thought would be useful in some loop to shorten the code, but I do not know how to define the loop.

How can I simplify the assignment of JSON values into tags .html to avoid 30 lines of $('Id').html(data.string) in my script?

received JSON data format: {"itemp1":"24","itemp1d":"8"}

tags with defined Ids:

```
<p id="itemp1" class="dfont1"></p>      
<p id="itemp1d" class="dfont3"></p>
```

working function - to be simplified for 30 tags:

```
function GetIndexData() {
    var param = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
    $.getJSON( 'index.js' , param , function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#itemp1').html(data.itemp1);
        $('#itemp1d').html(data.itemp1d);
        // ... 30x

        // ? how to simplify this part with some loop?

    });
    setTimeout(GetIndexData, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's something like:

```
for(var key in data) {
    $("#"+key).html(data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the object property keys and the element id looks the same, use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate through all properties of `data` and set the value

```
function GetIndexData() {
    var param = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
    $.getJSON('index.js', param, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            $('#' + key).html(val);
        })
    });
    setTimeout(GetIndexData, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop your data object :

```
function GetIndexData() {
    var param = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
    $.getJSON( 'index.js' , param , function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for(var id in data) {
            $('#'+id).html(data[id]);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(GetIndexData, 5000);
}
```